# Fastest way to download/access files in Amazon S3

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to access files in my amazon S3 and do some operations on it. Currently evaluating the options.

Since I will be doing some operations on the S3 files, I would prefer using some language to access the files in S3 (I have already tried copy command).

My S3 contains JSON files which range between 2MB to 4 MB and I would need to parse these JSON and load them into a database (thinking about using JQuery here, but any other suggestions are welcome)

Given these requirements which is most efficient language/platform to be used here.

Comment: Your question is rather broad and opinion-based. Do you have any preferred language? Have you tried something already? Alternatively, can you give more information about the actions you intend to perform, so we can recommend a language that might be more-suitable for the task?

Answer (score 1):

You options are pretty broad here. AWS has a list of SDKs for you to choose from. https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk

So your comfort level with a particular language should be your largest influencer.  Given that you mentioned JSON and JQuery perhaps you should look at Node.js SDK and AWS Lambda.